# Guessing initial parameters for global optimization

Tags: python, optimization, curve-fitting, simulated-annealing

I am trying to perform a global optimization fit routine, using dual annealing algorithm. After testing the code over synthetic data (which it works), I am now trying to analyze experimental ones. Unfortunately the fit return quite a linear behavior which does not capture the real trend of the data. I am assuming that the problem here is the initial values I am giving to my parameters. I honestly have no idea which value should I assign to them. Can someone give me a small hint?
Is there any additional evaluation I can do to assign values or check the correctness of the fit?
Below the code.

```
def fit_msd3(params,t,data):
    A = params['A']
    B = params['B']
    a = params['a']
    C = params['C']
    b = params['b']
    

    model = A*t + B * (1 - np.exp(-a*t))+ C * (1 - np.exp(-b*t)) 
    return np.log(model) - np.log(data)
```

```
# create a set of Parameters
params = Parameters()

params.add('B',  value = 0, min=0, max = 1000000)
params.add('A',  min=0.0001, max = 1000000)
params.add('a', value=0.25, min=0.0001, max = 1000000)
params.add('C', min=0, max = 1000000)
params.add('b',  value = 0.16, min=0.0001, max = 1000000)
```

```
x =[ 4.,  6.,   8.,  10.,  14.,  18.,  22.,  28., 36.,  44.,  54.,  66.,  82., 102.,126., 154., 190., 234., 286., 350., 428., 524., 642., 786.]
y = [1.15665197,   2.54089084,  4.39305993,  6.65139545,  12.16321355, 18.71986828,  26.05988679, 38.11383458,  55.45630159,  73.4806873, 95.87748006, 122.00380449, 155.64913134, 195.18638036, 236.78299798, 275.1298213, 315.73083698, 363.20054857, 410.54976453, 449.63215925, 476.15782442, 513.45335548, 589.47002132, 609.59510735]

plt.plot(np.log(x),np.log(y))
opt_args = {'initial_temp': 1050000, 'accept': -2.}
minner = Minimizer(fit_msd3, params, fcn_args=(x, y), max_nfev = 20000000)
result = minner.minimize(method="dual_annealing", **opt_args)

# show results
report_fit(result)
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,15))
ax.grid()
ax.set_ylabel('$\Delta_{msd}$(t) [$\mu$m]', fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel('Time Lag $\Delta t$ [s]', fontsize=18)
ax.plot(np.log(x), np.log(y), 'ko', lw=2)
ax.plot(np.log(x), np.log(y)+result.residual, 'r-', lw=2)

plt.legend(['data', 'dual anneal'], loc='upper left')
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code the coefficients B and C are supposed to be both positive because Bmin=0 and Cmin=0 are stated. This might be a cause of bad optimization.

Another software gives the result below :

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the help. Which kind of software did you use? For me setting negative boundaries to B and C produces Nan values in the fit. Also your plots look quite different from each other.. Why is it so?

Comment: The plots are the drawing of the same fitted function but with different scales on the axes. The first is with linear scales. The second is with logaritmic scales.

Comment: I use an home-made software for non-linear regression. It isn't public (interactive, not portable, ...). The curves are ploted with MathCad.

Comment: still setting the boundaries of B and C to a negative range returns Nan values in the fit.

Comment: Try your software with initial values for A,B,C,a,b not too far from those given in my answer. Also state the range of each one (min, max.) not too wide around those values.

Comment: Hi, my fit results are quite different from yours.. Also the scale of my data in log log scale results to be much smaller than yours.

Comment: Since I cannot see your graph and I don't know what are the values of A,B,C,a,b that you got I have no more comment. I am pleased that you succeed to run your software without NaN. Bye-Bye.